# Armadillo: changing a subview to the same value

Tags: c++, c++11, armadillo

I have just started using Armadillo and I am trying to change some of the values in a vector to the same value.  I know for changing to 0 or 1 you can do it easily.

Why does the last line in this not work?  The only way I have found to do this is much more complicated.

```
    arma::vec x = arma::linspace<arma::vec>(1, 20, 10);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    x(arma::find(x > 15)).ones();
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    x(arma::find(x < 6)) = arma::datum::nan; // this doesn't compile
```

// this is how I got it to work but is there a better way?

```
    arma::uvec idx = find(x < 6);
    arma::vec idxrepl(idx.n_elem);
    idxrepl.fill(arma::datum::nan);
    x.elem(idx) = idxrepl;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
x(arma::find(x < 6)).fill(arma::datum::nan);
```

Comment: is there a way in armadillo to do ANDS or ORS for something like this? x(arma::find(x < 6) && arma::find(x > 1)).fill(arma::datum::nan); this compiles but gives an error because of wrong sizes since the result are indices not booleans